# Spring Boot and Spring Session, disable auto configuration in SessionAutoConfigure.java

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

We have a use case to not use Spring session, i.e. not have `@EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation even though Spring Session and Spring boot are in the classpath. We used to do that by having a custom property `spring.session.enabled` and having a `@ConditionalOnProperty` on the class that had the `@EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation. This worked in Spring boot 1.2.7. However with Spring Boot 1.3.0, the `SessionAutoConfiguration` class has a `@EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation on it.

Is there a way to disable the class from being used?

Comment: The simple way is not to have `spring-session` on the classpath. But if you don't want this, exclude the `SessionAutoConfiguration` by default and then add another configuration class which registers the `SessionAutoConfiguration` when the property is set to `true`.

Comment: How do I exclude SessionAutoConfiguration by default?

Comment: You can specify in the `@SpringBootApplication` or `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which configuration to exclude.

Answer (score 7):

To disable Spring Boot Auto-Configuration of Spring Session:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SessionAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application
{
 ...
}
```

Then, to enable Spring Session depending on a property (for example, you may want it disabled when in development but enabled in production):

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "spring.session.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig
{
 ...
}
```

> I had the same question and through the comments, I was able to get my answer so I'm putting this down here so the question is marked as answered:

Comment: Is the above solution help to remove the jsesssionId from the Cookie?

Comment: @BindumaliniKK - no. jsessionId is put there by the application container (Tomcat, or whatever you use).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Spring Session by setting this property in `application.properties`, or via any of the other various ways of setting properties in Spring:

```
spring.session.store-type=none
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-session.html